# Unable to locate node nifi-0 to seed policies

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new to Nifi and K8s and would be grateful for some help.
The end result needs to be a nifi cluster with zookeepeer.
Using certs and keys supplied from a corporate CA.
steps so far

1. create truststore.jks and keystore.p12 from supplied certs.

openssl pkcs12 -export -in ./deployment/nifi/certs/xxxx.uk_ssl_certificate.cer -inkey ./deployment/nifi/certs/_.xxxx.uk_private_key.key -certfile ./deployment/nifi/certs/xxxx.uk_ssl_certificate.cer  -name "xxxxcert" -out ./deployment/nifi/certs/keystore.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ./deployment/nifi/certs/keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore ./deployment/nifi/certs/truststore.jks -deststoretype JKS

2. create configmaps for later

sudo kubectl apply -f deployment/nifi/namespace.yml

sudo kubectl -n nifi create configmap keystore-cm --from-file=./deployment/nifi/certs/keystore.p12
sudo kubectl -n nifi create configmap truststore-cm --from-file=./deployment/nifi/certs/truststore.jks

these could be read  ok using keytool -list -keystore

3. run kustomize

kubectl apply -k ./deploymnet./

4 I get error
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate node nifi-0 to seed policies.

logs from command:
sudo  kubectl -n nifi logs statefulset.apps/nifi | grep seed

notes: the code is here
https://gitlab.com/awedmondson/k8s-nifi/-/tree/main

the config for the variables are set here

https://gitlab.com/awedmondson/k8s-nifi

the plan is eventually to use auth: oidc, but for now, to test I've set auth to tls

Thanks in advance for any help on this.
(original code from https://github.com/saidsef/k8s-nifi-cluster)